# Making rice wine

Tags: fermentation, wine

I am brewing rice wine using baker's yeast. Can i use baker's yeast for brewing rice wine? Will it affect to the quality of wine? I want to also know, can it get over fermented? What happens during over fermentation? Will it affect to the alcohol content?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by over fermentation?

Comment: there are a lot of rice wines out there...are you making something like makkoli?  will you distill it after?  need...more...info!

Comment: See http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/baking-yeast-for-brewing regarding the yeast.

Comment: How did the bakers yeast work out? Good I hope. I'm finding it hard to find yeast balls in India, so I may try the bakers yeast substitute. I'm mixing I've rice wine with fruit juice anyway to make a Sangeree/sangria. Also trying to find a source of glutinous rice in India. Any success with other rice types please? Any subsections would be good. Cheers, Alex,

Answer (score 1):

Baker's yeast is not bred for producing rice wine which is high in alchohol. You should try using some yeast that was bred specifically for that purpose. I don't know if you want to make something like [sake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sake) (not all rice wines = sake), but the major American yeast suppliers both sell high quality yeasts made specifically for sake.

- [Wyeast sake #9](https://www.wyeastlab.com/he_s_yeaststrain_detail.cfm?ID=43)
- [White labs sake wlp 705](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp705-sake-yeast)
- [White labs sake #9](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp709-sake-9-yeast)

These area all good products with alcohol tolerances in the 14-16% ABV range. You can use other yeasts with high alcohol tolerances as well, but you may not get the flavors you're looking for.

Sake making also requires several other steps, including growing the koji mold spores on the rice. This is necessary in order to get fermentable sugar for the yeast to eat. Michael Tonsmeire documented the process on his [Mad Fermentationist](http://www.themadfermentationist.com/search/label/Sake) blog. You may want to get a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1468147781) or do additional research on homebrewing rice wine/sake.

Answer (score -2):

Bakers yeast may not be alcohol tolerant, and therefore not produce the result you want.

Comment: This is not true. Bakers yeast will create alcohol just fine... however, the character and flavour of the alcohol will be somewhat more... 'bready', not really what is desired in a beer.